# Cannot install hashids gem on (ruby/sinatra)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, hashids

I installed hashids gem as instructed here:
https://github.com/peterhellberg/hashids.rb

However, when I try to use the Hashids class it shows me an error as if it doesn't know this class:

> NameError at / uninitialized constant Hashids

This is the code where it fails:

```
tocode = Hashids.new("test")
```

I am not even sure how to debug this as I am new to ruby. I know that the class is defined in the Hashids library. I don't think I am supposed to use 'required' as I installed this as a gem. When I run 'gem list' I see that gem there:

hashids (1.0.3)

Comment: add `require "hashids"` at the top

Comment: Thanks Bartosz. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

After you installed the `Hashids` gem, it will not add to your `$LOAD_PATH` by default, when your say `Hashids.new("test")` ruby will try to find `Hashids` in your `$LOAD_PATH`, it will raise `NameError at / uninitialized constant Hashids` once it can't be found. To append `Hashids` to your `$LOAD_PATH`, your need

```
require "hashids"
```

before you use it.

Comment: Thanks. That worked! I tried adding 'require' yesterday, but it was throwing an error that it couldn't find such file. Today it all works...